# How can a variable check through an empty dictionary

Tags: python, list, function, loops, dictionary

```
content_ratings = {}
ratings = ['4+', '4+', '4+', '9+', '9+', '12+', '17+']

for c_rating in ratings:
    # why is the variable c_rating checking the empty dictionary
    if c_rating in content_ratings: 
        content_ratings[c_rating] += 1
    else:
        content_ratings[c_rating] = 1
    print(content_ratings)

print('Final dictionary:')
print(content_ratings)
```

Comment: This is where my confusion lies: as a beginner python coder, i want to know how the variable c-rating under the if statement can check through an empty dictionary and if it exists, then increment same key value by 1

Comment: This clearly does not show ANY attempt to search online.

Answer (score 0):

@Yuppie, The if is used for verifying if the rating has already been added to the dictionary in a previous loop. If so, it will increment the current value. Otherwise, it will basically initialize it to 1.

Comment: Thanks, i understand your argument clearly. from my understanding of the "if statement" if c_ratings in ratings: means if the variable exist in ratings where ratings is an empty dictionary. i no fully well that the same dictionary is empty, why is there a result?

Comment: Actually, the sentence "if  c_rating in content_ratings" is checking if a key named "c_rating" is present in the "content_ratings" dictionary. If the key is not in there, then the evaluation will be False. This would also be the case for an empty dictionary (no keys in there)...

Answer (score 0):

Same as eespejel said, c_ratings is the variable that is there to place hold a certain item in the list, going from the first item to the last. Then you do something with the c_ratings variable, like test if c_ratings is already inside the dictionary content_ratings. IF it is already there, increment that score by one. ELSE (if all previous ifs and elifs werent satisfied, set that value to one in the dictionary. This is why when the dictionary is empty, the ELSE is being run, because c_ratings is definitely not in the dictionary, when it is empty.